# How to match Chinese character in the web pages whose charset is big5 (Perl)?

Tags: perl

I am doing a match between Chinese words, for example, "语言中心“ and a mount of web files (php, html, htm, etc).

However, somehow I get the following error:

```
Malformed UTF-8 character (1 byte, need 2, after start byte 0xdf) in regexp compilation at ../Final_FindOnlyNoReplace_CLE_Chinese.pl line 89, <INFILE> line 12.
```

Can anyone help?

Here is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Encode qw/encode decode/;

use utf8;
use strict;
use Cwd;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my($path) = @_;

## append a trailing / if it's not there
$path .= '/' if($path !~ /\/$/);

use File::Glob ':glob';

my @all_files = bsd_glob($path."*");

for my $eachFile (@all_files) {
    open(INFILE, "<$eachFile") || die ("Could not open '$eachFile'\n");

    my(@inlines) = <INFILE>;
    my($line, $find);
    my $outkey = 1;

    foreach $line (@inlines) {
        $find = &find($line);
        if ($find ne 'false') {
            chomp($line);
            print "\tline$outkey : $line\n"; 
        }
        $outkey ++;
    }
}

#subroutine
sub find {
    my $m = encode("utf8", decode("big5", @_));

    my $html = LWP::UserAgent->new
        ->get($m)
        ->decoded_content;
    my $str_chinese = '語言中心';

    if ($m =~ /$str_chinese/) {  
        $m; ##if match, return the whole line.
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give address of one of your pages where you expect to find the string?

Comment: they are static files saved in my server. <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled 語言中心 Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=big5">
</head>

<body>
abc 語言中心 cde
dfgdgfdhgf
天天向上語言中心他
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

You aren't searching in `$html` you've retrieved and decoded, but in URL instead: `$m =~ /$str_chinese/`, which, I guess, is not what you intend.

Also, you're comparing result of `find` function with exact string "false," which will never work. Change `if ($find ne 'false')` to `if (defined($find))` and add explicit returns for success and failure to `find` for clarity.

Finally, you script seems to fail because you point it to directory that have some other Perl scripts amongst other files. They're most likely in UTF-8, so when your script tries to read them as big5 data, it falis on decoding. Just change your glob to cover data files only.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use utf8;
use strictures;
use LWP::UserAgent qw();
use Path::Class::Rule qw();
use URI::file qw();

my $start_directory = q(.);
my $search_text = qr'語言中心';

my $next = Path::Class::Rule->new->name(qw(*.php *.htm*))->iter($start_directory);

my @matching_lines;
while (my $file = $next->()) {
    for my $line (split /\R/, LWP::UserAgent
        ->new
        ->get(URI::file->new_abs($file))
        ->decoded_content
    ) {
        push @matching_lines, $line if $line =~ $search_text;
    }
}
# @matching_lines is (
#     '<title>Untitled 語言中心 Document</title>',
#     'abc 語言中心 cde',
#     '天天向上語言中心他'
# )
```